# Why My Unique Index Doesn't Work in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I created a table for to store day off data of users. After, set a unique index for multi column but when exec insert sql, it duplicates datas again

Here's my DDL:

```sql
create table day_off_movements
(
    id                 bigserial
        primary key,
    user_id            bigint
        constraint fk_day_off_movements_user
            references users,
    proxy_user_id      bigint
        constraint fk_day_off_movements_proxy_users
            references users,
    reason             text,
    day_off_start_date timestamp with time zone,
    day_off_end_date   timestamp with time zone,
    used_days          bigint,
    created_at         timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at         timestamp with time zone
);
```

Index:

```sql
create unique index idx_day_off_all
    on day_off_movements (user_id, proxy_user_id, day_off_start_date, day_off_end_date);
```

Control query:

```sql
SELECT user_id,proxy_user_id,day_off_end_date,day_off_start_date,count(*)
                 FROM public.day_off_movements t
GROUP BY user_id, proxy_user_id, day_off_end_date, day_off_start_date
```

Output as json:

```json
[
  {
    "user_id": 961,
    "proxy_user_id": null,
    "day_off_end_date": "2020-07-29 00:00:00.000000 +00:00",
    "day_off_start_date": "2020-07-27 00:00:00.000000 +00:00",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

What is my wrong?
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You are aware that that index won't give an error if two rows have the same `user_id`? Only if *all* columns are the same, the unique index will give you an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you've created a unique index on the columns `user_id`, `proxy_user_id`, `day_off_start_date`, and `day_off_end_date`. This means that the combination of these **four** columns should be unique in your table. However, in your JSON, you have a ***null*** value for `proxy_user_id`.

In SQL, ***null*** is not considered a value, and it does not participate in uniqueness constraints in the same way that other values do. This means that multiple rows with ***null*** in the `proxy_user_id` field will not violate the unique index, even if the other fields (`user_id`, `day_off_start_date`, and `day_off_end_date`) are the same.

If you want to prevent this, you have a few options:

- Disallow nulls in the `proxy_user_id` field
- Use a placeholder value instead of ***null*** values in JSON
- Use a partial index

Here's an example of how you might create a partial index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_day_off_all
ON day_off_movements (
    user_id, 
    proxy_user_id, 
    day_off_start_date,
    day_off_end_date
)
WHERE proxy_user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

This would enforce the uniqueness constraint for all rows where `proxy_user_id` is not null, but would allow multiple rows with the same `user_id`, `day_off_start_date`, and `day_off_end_date` if `proxy_user_id` is null.

Comment: OMG! I didn't realize. Thanks for solution and kindly, clear explanation.

Comment: Another option, new in v15, is putting `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` on the index.

Answer (score 5):

Null values are not considered equal to **any** other value, including other nulls (or even itself!). This is not peculiar to Postgres: It's the SQL standard.

Comment: Unless you put ‘nulls not distinct ‘ in the constraint definition. Available since version 15